# Check(conditional) if the current url is the same with a url declared in path

Tags: django, django-views

In the main urls.py I have:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('items/', include('items.urls', namespace='items')),
    ....
]
```

In items urls.py I have:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('item/add/', ItemCreateView.as_view(), name='create_item'),

]
```

I want to check in a view/dispatch() if the current page url is the same with the one in the path, something like:

```
if self.request.path == 'items:create_items'
```

Comment: What if the URL contains parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) to convert the namespaced pattern name `items:create` to the URL.

```
from django.urls import reverse

if self.request.path == reverse('items:create_items'):
```

Depending on your server setup and whether you are concerned about the querystring, you may want to use [`request.path_info`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path_info) or [`request.get_full_path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path_info) instead of [`request.path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path_info).